# Parse Text File Line by Line, Skipping Certain Lines

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

I have a file that looks like this (but is much bigger):

```
>some text
ABC
DEF
GHI
>some more text
JKL
MNO
PQR
```

I have been playing around with it in Java for some time and have been able to build arrays with the lines, etc.  The lines with '>' are usually one line but sometimes could be 2, 3 or more lines.  The lines that don't begin with '>' are the same length in characters but there may be 10, 20 or 30 or more of these lines.  I am at the point now where I want to create an string array, where each string in the array contains a string of the lines that don't begin with '>' like so:

```
array element 1 = ABCDEFGHI
array element 2 = JKLMONPQR
```

I feel like I am close but need a small kick in the butt to get me going.  I'm sure this is easy for a pro, but I am still new to Java.

**Specific problem** is related to other posts I made on this board.  It's a FASTA file:

```
>3BHS_BOVIN (P14893) 3 beta-hydroxysteroid
AGWSCLVTGGGGFLGQRIICLLVEEKDLQEIRVLDKVFRPEVREEFSKLQSKIKLTLLEG
DILDEQCLKGACQGTSVVIHTASVIDVRNAVPRETIMNVNVKGTQLLLEACVQASVPVFI
>41_BOVIN (Q9N179) Protein 4.1 
MHCKVSLLDDTVYECVVEKHAKGQDLLKRVCEHLNLLEEDYFGLAIWDNATSKTWLDSAK
EIKKQVRGVPWNFTFNVKFYPPDPAQLTEDITRYYLCLQLRQDIVSGRLPCSFATLALLG
SYTIQSELGDYDPELHGADYVSDFKLAPNQTKELEEKVMELHKSYRSMTPAQADLEFLEN
>5NTD_BOVIN (Q05927) 5'-nucleotidase 
MNPGAARTPALRILPLGALLWPAARPWELTILHTNDVHSRLEQTSEDSSKCVNASRCVGG
VARLATKVHQIRRAEPHVLLLDAGDQYQGTIWFTVYKGTEVAHFMNALGYESMALGNHEF
DNGVEGLIDPLLKEVNFPILSANIKAKGPLASKISGLYSPYKILTVGDEVVGIVGYTSKE
TPFLSNPGTNLVFEDEITALQPEVDKLKTLNVNKIIALGHSGFEVDKLIAQKVKGVDVVV
```

I ultimately need the sequences in their own array element so that I can manipulate them later.

Comment: What is the *specific* problem?  Do you know how to concatenate strings?  Do you know know how to identify whether a string starts with a `'>'`?

Comment: I have an array of lines from a file and I can determine which begin with '>', yes...  I can concatenate lines as well, but choosing only those and putting them as an element in an array is where I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can iterate over the lines:

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (String line : lines) {
  if (line.startsWith(">")) {
    if (buf.length() > 0) {
      array.add(buf.toString());
      buf.setLength(0);
    }
  } else {
    buf.append(line);
  }
}
if (buf.length() > 0) { // Add the final text element(s).
  array.add(buf.toString());
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution.  Seems tight and efficient, except for one thing.  For testing, since I'm using a file with three entries, if I print the array, I only get the first two entries and if I print buf, I get the third entry.  It's a good start and I'm working with it now to see if I can get it to work all the way.  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @nicorellius: oops, right, I forgot to flush the buffer at the end of the loop; see my updated solution.

Comment: nice!  I thought it was a bit off.  You made it perfect, though ;--)  Thanks again for the great response.

Comment: @nicorellius: glad it helps!  If you think this solution answers your question then consider pressing the checkmark icon to mark this one as "accepted".

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I didn't bother with proper variable names. Also it works assuming first line has a >. It's probably not optimised either but should give you an idea of how this is possible.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Parse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String lala = ">some text\r\n" + 
                "ABC\r\n" + 
                "DEF\r\n" + 
                "GHI\r\n" + 
                ">some more text\r\n" + 
                "JKL\r\n" + 
                "MNO\r\n" + 
                "PQR";

        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new StringReader( lala ) );

        String line;
        while( ( line = in.readLine() ) != null ) {
            lines.add( line );
        }

        ArrayList<String> parsed = new ArrayList<String>();

        for( String s : lines ) {
            if( s.contains(">") ) {
                parsed.add("");
            } else {
                String current = parsed.get( parsed.size() - 1 );
                parsed.set( parsed.size() - 1, current + s );
            }
        }

        for( String s : parsed ) {
            System.out.println( s );
        }
    }

}
```

The above will output:

```
ABCDEFGHI
JKLMNOPQR
```

Another interesting way you could do it is at the 'in.readLine()' loop you can check for the > and if it exists add a < at the end of that string before pushing it onto 'lines'. You can then use a regex to grab the other lines back out later.

Comment: Why would you add the lines first to an array and then iterate through the array again to remove the unnecessary entries instead of just adding the useful lines? Way too complicated imo

Comment: You can do this. It's slightly trickier since you'll probably have to go backwards since you'll be deleting entries from the list. I guess it's preference. I would disagree that my method was a lot more complicated than the one you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
Array<String> lines    
 //Open the file for reading
    try {    
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(<FileNameGoesHere>));
       while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) { // while loop begins here
         if(thisLine.charAt(0) != '>') {
           lines.add(thisLine);
         }
       } // end while 
     } // end try
     catch (IOException e) {
       System.err.println("Error: " + e);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

skipping the lines starting with `>` is easy;

```
while((line=istream.readLine())!=null){
    if(line.charAt(0)=='>')continue;

    //do normal concat to buffers
}
```

if you want to go to the next buffer on lines starting with `>` is a bit more involved

```
while((line=istream.readLine())!=null){
    if(line.charAt(0)=='>'){
         //create new buffer and append the current one to the list (check first if current one is not empty)
         continue;
    }

    //do normal concat to buffer
}
```