# Processing - parsing a text file, omitting certain lines with loadStrings()

Tags: arrays, arraylist, processing

I have a text file of file paths, and need an array of those file paths. However, some of the file paths are "commented" out, with an exclamation mark at the beginning of the line, and I do not want to include these lines in the array.

Currently I am placing the entire text file in an array using `loadStrings()`, then iterating over the entire array and placing only the elements that do not begin with "!" in a `StringList`, before converting the `StringList` back into an array, thus acquiring an array containing only the "un-commented" file paths, with no surplus space.

This seems horrendously inefficient and cumbersome, so does anyone know of a better way of achieving this? Is there a way to ignore the lines beginning with "!" at the original read stage, or failing that, a way to easily remove these elements from the first array, and resize that array accordingly?

Current code:

```java
String file = "File_Paths.txt";
String[] filePaths_raw = loadStrings(file);
StringList filePaths = new StringList();

for (int i = 0; i < filePaths_raw.length; i++) {
  if (filePaths_raw[i].charAt(0) != 33) {
    filePaths.append(filePaths_raw[i]);
  }
}

filePathsArray = new String[filePaths.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < filePathsArray.length; i++) {
  filePathsArray[i] = filePaths.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351224/parse-text-file-line-by-line-skipping-certain-lines ?

Comment: Not specifically, as the processing `loadStrings()` function parses the whole file in one go I believe - can I step through, reading the file line by line, as is possible in Java?

Comment: Yes, using [BufferedReader](https://processing.org/reference/BufferedReader.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is fine.

Reading the file takes O(N) time, where N is the number of lines in the file.

Iterating over the array takes another O(N) time, which you do twice. So your total time is 3*O(N), which is O(N). Doing this in a single loop would still be O(N) time. So in the grand scheme of things, this isn't really woefully inefficient.

You could simplify your code by using the `array()` function, which creates an array from a `StringList`. That wouldn't speed your code up (which probably isn't something you should be worried about anyway), but it will eliminate that last `for` loop. More info is available in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/StringList_array_.html).